# Search By Column in Laravel/Lighthouse GraphQL API

Tags: graphql

currently i'm creating a GraphQL implementation of an existing API.

i want to create Search Function not with primary column, which is not id, but id_position.

here is my scheme :

```
type Query @guard {
    subordinate(
        positionId: ID
    ): [Employee!]! @all
}

type Position @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID
    name: String
}

"Account of a person who utilizes this application."
type Employee @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID
    name: String
    id_position: Int
}
```

but, when I run this :

```
  query EmployeeSubordinate($id: ID) {
    subordinate(positionId: $id) {
      name
    }
}
```

```
{
    "id" : 93
}
```

I ve got result all rows of employee, not employee with `id_position = 93`

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
type Query @guard {
    subordinate(
        positionId: ID
    ): [Employee!]! @all
}
```

The `@all` is getting all records from DB [@all docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#all)

The correct way is this

```
type Query @guard {
    subordinate(
        positionId: ID
    ): Employee
}
```

I removed `!` from `Employee` because your `ID` is not required, so in some cases it masy return `null`, i you handle like thatin backend.
And alsoe I removed `[]` because you no longer getting many `Employee` you just getting one.